# sonar-scanner: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar-scanner to analyze C++ code, and this did work, but it no longer works after upgrading from 7.0 to 7.1.  I even made sure to upgrade sonar-scanner itself, but to no avail.  It seems to having problems loading the branch configuration, but I don't understand what it is having problem with. I am also setting the -Dsonar.branch.name= setting, but even if I remove it I get the same error. Any ideas?

```
INFO: Load project branches
INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=79ms
INFO: Load branch configuration
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.868s
INFO: Final Memory: 26M/196M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.DefaultInputModuleHierarchy
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectBuildersExecutor
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.CommitProjectBuilder
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.GitLabPluginConfiguration
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.MutableProjectSettings
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration
ERROR: Caused by: com.sonarsource.branch.A.load(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/ProjectBranches;Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/ProjectPullRequests;)Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/BranchConfiguration;
```

Extended debug:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        ... 111 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sonarsource.branch.A.load(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/ProjectBranches;Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/ProjectPullRequests;)Lorg/sonar/scanner/scan/branch/BranchConfiguration;
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfigurationProvider.provide(BranchConfigurationProvider.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
```

Comment: Please add versions of SonarScanner and installed plugins.

Comment: SonarQube: 7.1.0.11001

Branch plugin
1.0 (build 507)installed
HomepageIssue Tracker
Licensed under SonarSource
Developed by SonarSource
Installed

Developer
Developer oriented features
1.0 (build 240)installed
HomepageIssue Tracker
Licensed under SonarSource
Developed by SonarSource
Installed

SonarCFamily
Code Analyzer for C, C++, Objective-C
5.0 (build 9359)installed

Comment: You forgot to add version of SonarQube Scanner.

Comment: Sorry, using latest: 3.1.0.1141 version of sonar scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade the [Branch](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/branch.html) plugin to at least 7.1:

```
+------------------------+---------+-----------+
|   SonarQube Version    | 6.7 LTS | 7.0 | 7.1 |
|------------------------|---------|-----------|
| Branch minimal version |   1.0   | 7.0 | 7.1 |
+------------------------+---------+-----------+
```

Read plugin version compatibility matrix [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix).

Comment: The problem was my proxy wasn't setup correctly in sonarqube, so the plugins weren't getting updated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update sonar-gitlab-plugin for new release (Version 4.1.0-SNAPSHOT):

https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases